# Is there a way to express fixed size loops as loop-less expansion statement in bash?

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I was wondering whether expansion of `{}` in bash shell, e.g. of `command /path/to/file{1,2,3}` works "horizontally", i.e.

```
command /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 /path/to/file3
```

or "vertically", i.e.

```
command /path/to/file1
command /path/to/file2
command /path/to/file3
```

It works "horizontally". Is there a way to achieve "vertical" expansion as described here without using loops, i.e. in an equally easy way, like specifying the equivalent of `{}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can echo the result and pipe it to `xargs -n1`:

```
echo /path/to/file{1,2,3} | xargs -n1 command
```